# Custom Confirm Form by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I use `return confirm(Message);` when need confirmation in a form. that cause displaye a form with two button `OK` and `Cancel`. Is there any way to change the buttons text in displayed form? I need to change buttons to another language? what is your suggestion?

Comment: The buttons automatically change according to the user's browser setting language. If you are trying to do this only to account for the user's language, it's best to just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged jquery, [jQuery UI Modal Confirm](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) is definitely worth a look

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/GR2UT/

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the button text on a native `confirm` box. You can program your own modal dialog, which would give you control to what's in the buttons. In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/X5DuY/) you'll find a plain javascript example. Or use JQuery, like [naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17447/naveen) suggested.